# Confirm() causing phone to freeze

Tags: javascript, bind, confirm

Im developing a new feature for a website that uses the js confirm() prompt. After many tests every time I run even the simplest confirm function it causes my phone to freeze. Is there a reason for this and could it be a potential problem going forward?`

```
var check = function(){
   var ask = confirm("are you sure?") 
   if(ask === true){
      console.log("message confirmed")
   }
   else{
       console.log("never mind")
   }
}
$("element").mousedown(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(confirm, 1000);

 }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
 });
```

Comment: What phone and what browser and version?

Comment: Yeah, just don't use `confirm`.

Comment: Did you mean `setTimeout(check, 1000)` instead of `setTimeout(confirm, 1000)`?

Comment: yeah sorry i rewrote it for the question just a typo. its a samsung s4 mini its okay though, i figured out it was the bind method that was causing the problem i found another way a achieve a similar effect though